# Unknown SetProcessDpiAwareness Error Result

Tags: vb.net, winapi, hdpi

I have 1 computer out of 50 that is returning a non zero result from SetProcessDpiAwareness and I can't find any information on it.  I am setting the DPI Awareness to Unaware.  I have one computer that is returning a value of 105621835743232(Decimal).  It seems to still be setting the DPI Awareness to unaware like it should but gives a return value that is not expected.

```
Private Declare Function SetProcessDpiAwareness Lib "shcore.dll" (ByVal Value As PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS) As Long

Private Function SetDPI() As Long
    'Results from SetProcessDPIAwareness
    'Const S_OK = &H0&
    'Const E_INVALIDARG = &H80070057
    'Const E_ACCESSDENIED = &H80070005
    Dim lngResult As Long
    lngResult = SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS.Process_DPI_Unaware)
    Return lngResult

End Function
```

This is a clickonce winforms application so I can't use the manifest to set DPI.

Any help with locating documentation would be greatly welcomed!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This API function's return value is a 32 bit integer so you should use `Integer` rather than `Long`. Note that `Long` is a 64 bit type.

I also strongly recommend using p/invoke rather than `Declare`. The latter exists for compatibility reasons. P/invoke offers much greater control of the import process.

Comment: Decimal 105621835743232 is hex 0x0000601000000000. The lower 32 bits are all 0s, which means the function is actually returning an HRESULT of 0x00000000, aka S_OK: "*The DPI awareness for the app was set successfully.*"

Comment: Thanks for the catch David.  I read the documentation for that call a bunch of time and missed the fact that the return was a 32 bit integer.  That makes much more sense as to why it was still working even though it was return a non zero number.